# What is wrong with my Factorial Function logic?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement, factorial

I'm trying to get a factorial number in the JS console in Chrome.
Obviously, there is something wrong with my understanding of the for loop, and I'd like to know what part of it is not logical to me.
Thank you very much for answers <3

```
var newX

function factorial(x) {
    if(x > 0){
        for(i = 1;i <= x;i++){
            var newX = x * i ;
} return newX;
};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you said `var newX = x * i;`, that declares a new variable. Remove `var`.
`x * i` will return the square of `x` because lastly `i` is x.

```js
function factorial(x) {
    var newX = 1;
    if(x > 0){
        for(var i = 1;i <= x;i++){
            newX = newX * i;
        }
        return newX;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};
console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(4));
console.log(factorial(0));
```

Comment: Yeap, Thank you! 
I'll compare these two and think it through. (Btw, someone was clearly angry "-1")
Thanks again.

Comment: What about `console.log(factorial(5)); console.log(factorial(0));` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `var` inside the for loop. Also, you should move the declaration of `newX` inside the function. And there's some other errors too.

```
function factorial(x) {
    var newX = 1
    if(x > 0){
        for(i = 1;i <= x;i++){
            newX = newX * i ;
        } 
    return newX;
    }
}
```

Also, for completeness, you should return 1 when x is 0 and NaN when x is negative or not an integer.

You could rewrite it as a recursive function:

```
function factorial(x) {
    if(x == 0) return 1;
    return x*factorial(x-1);
}
```

Looks way cleaner.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. 
factorial(5) should give me: 120

Comment: @KaietanPaul Fixed it

Comment: Yup, it works.
I wanted to get my logic fixed so plus for @Yousername
Thank you anyways <3

Answer (score 0):

writing var newX in loop means making new variable every time till loop is executing and another thing is you are multiplying x*i but it should be newX *=  i to satisfy the condition of factorial (i.e every time you have to multiply the result with next number ).

```
var newX=1;
function factorial(x) {    if(x > 0){
 for(i = 1;i <= x;i++){ newX *=  i ;
} return newX;  }; };
```

Comment: You are right in principle but not in javascript. Variable's *scope* is **function** where it is defined. So `var newX` in the loop is OK.